# How do typedefs work with templates?

Tags: c++, templates, struct, typedef

I'm looking at the following code on my project and I cant seem to figure out how data is stored in the typedef's below. I am new to C++ so have a limited understanding of typedef's and templates. My searching for a good description of such scenarios has yielded few results.

My thinking is any typedef made from squareTemplate would have the 3 values: area, height, and width. But I'm not sure what the 
`<bool, bool>` and `<std::vector<std ::pair<double, double>>,std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>>`
does? Do all 3 typedefs contain area, height, and width variables? please explain.

```
template <Class D, Class I>
struct squareTemplate
{
    I area;
    D height;
    D width;

   squareTemplate() :
    area(),
    height(),
    width()
    {
    }
};
typedef squareTemplate <std::vector<std ::pair<double, double>>, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>> squareRange;

typedef squareTemplate <bool, bool> squareValid;

typedef squareTemplate<double, int> squareValue;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `typedef A B` you are simply saying that B is another name for A.

> Do all 3 typedefs contain area, height, and width variables?

Yes.  The `squareTemplate` template class is defined to have `area`, `height`, and `width` and all instantiations of it will have those members. In the case of your typedefs:

```
typedef squareTemplate <std::vector<std ::pair<double, double>>, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>> squareRange;
```

`area` has the type assumed by the first template parameter `D`, so `std::vector<std ::pair<double, double>>`; The same goes for `height` and `width` - they have the type of the second template argument, `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>`

Following the same reasoning, you get:

```
typedef squareTemplate <bool, bool> squareValid;
```

all of them are bool

```
typedef squareTemplate<double, int> squareValue;
```

`area` is `int`; `height` and `width` are `double`

Comment: Great explanation, I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A templated `class` is a special kind of `class`; instead of providing an implementation, it's basically a pattern the compiler can follow to create versions of that `class` (usually called instantiating the `template`).  Let's use the last `typedef` (`typedef squareTemplate<double, int> squareValue`) as an example.  You basically get code that's the moral equivalent of this:

```
struct squareTemplate_double_int
{
    int area;
    double height;
    double width;

   squareTemplate() :
    area(),
    height(),
    width()
    {
    }
};
```

The same thing happens for the first two `typedef`s as well: you get unique versions of the `squareTemplate` for any given pattern of `template` types.

Comment: I'm not following. My question is what does <bool, bool> do? i have no bools in the struct. I'm not understanding what values go here, how these bools would be accessed, and what happends to the area, height, and width

Comment: They're `template` parameters, so they're applied only when the compiler instantiates that specific version of `squareTemplate`.  Mentally replace every `D` with `bool` (the first `template` argument) and then replace every `I` with `bool` as well (the second `template` argument).

Comment: I wanted to expand your third `typedef` since the types are different; I thought it'd be more clear what was happening.

Comment: Thanks. This and ricab's answer both helped :)

Answer (score 0):

```
template <Class D, Class I>
struct squareTemplate
{
    I area;
    D height;
    D width;
    ...
}
```

First: This is not a "real" class. This is a template that the compiler can use to make classes.  Given template parameters `class D` and `class I`, the compiler can generate a "real" `squareTemplate` class.

```
typedef squareTemplate <double, int> squareValid;
```

This tells the compiler "use the `squareTemplate` template with the template parameters `D=double` and `I=int` to generate a "real" type, and we'll typedef that to `squareValid` so we have a reasonable name for this  type. And the compiler fills out the class as if it was like this:

```
struct squareTemplate_double_int
{
    int area;
    double height;
    double width;
    ...
}
typedef squareTemplate_double_int squareValid;
```

You don't *need* typedefs, you can just use them directly if you want:

void func() {
       squareTemplate object;
   }

But typedefs can keep things simple when the template parameters are long to type:

```
typedef squareTemplate <std::vector<std ::pair<double, double>>, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>> squareRange;
squareRange object;
```